# Prestashop redirect not exact url

Tags: url, redirect, http-status-code-404, prestashop

I need to redirect inaccurate URL to 404 page

What I mean:

**Existing URL**

*http://something.com/2-sport-shoes*

**Inaccurate URL**

*http://something.com/2-dsajdhasudhas* is redirected to *http://something.com/2-sport-shoes* as links share the same ID (`2`)

How in Prestashop do redirect inaccurate url to 404?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution

modification CategoryController

```
public function canonicalRedirection($canonical_url = '')
    {
        if (Tools::getValue('live_edit')) {
            return;
        }
        if (!Tools::getValue('noredirect') && Validate::isLoadedObject($this->category)) {
            $exact_url= parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
            $link = $this->category->id . "-" . $this->category->link_rewrite;
            if($exact_url != $link) {
                Tools::redirect('index.php?controller=404');

            }
        }
    }
```